# Facebook 'verified' field missing in subsequent calls

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am facing a weird issue with Facebook PHP sdk.

I am using both the Javascript and PHP sdk.

So whats happening is if I make a call to `/me?fields=verified` endpoint with the `PHP sdk` the very first request is successful and returns verified as true but any subsequent calls to the same endpoint throws an exception that-

> access token is invalid.

(I am not touching the access tokens in any subsequent requests).

I also checked that the Javascript api method works fine for this endpoint and I get verified:true for no matter how many requests I make.
It just fails on subsequent requests with PHP sdk.

Anyone facing a similar issue and was able to solve it, please help.

For reference Facebook doc for the above endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `verfied` field in particular – as the error message already says, you don’t have a valid (user) access token on your second call.

Comment: @Cbroe - but is it possible that the same access token works for endpoint: `/<facebook id>` but throws an exception of invalid token for endpoint `/me`? That is what is happening in my case. I have two api calls in one request from which the `/me` throws this exception: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user"

Comment: `/me` needs a _user_ access token – otherwise the API can’t figure out, who “me” is supposed to be. Whereas `/id` can also be accessed using the app access token (then you’ll only get the publicly available info). And when the PHP SDK is not able to get a valid user access token, then it falls back to using the app access token automatically.